# get current solver parameters in pycaffe

Tags: python-2.7, pycaffe

Is it possible to get the current parameters from eg an SGDsolver object when working with the caffe python interface? I'd like to trace and print out the learning rate which may update over time depending on lr_policy.
  Thank you!